# How to model time-schedules of a public transport system in a graph database?

Tags: database, neo4j, data-modeling, graph-databases

Suppose I want to model a public bus transport service with a graph database such as Neo4j.

Such service is constituted by a set bus stops, a set of lines and a set of time-schedules which relates lines with bus-stops.

Querying the database should answer questions such as what is the best route (for example by time or by walking the least possible or with the less number of changes) to go from a point of the city to another.

Following the most common guidelines bus-stops and lines become nodes each one having proper properties (ID's, geoposition and address for each stop and so on).

Each line has edges with labels `start` and `stop` the beginning and ending of a line service. Subsequent bus-stops are connected with other edges with some properties (such as the line(s), the distance between the two stops and others).

How to model time-schedules in such databases? Is it good to model them as a key-value property of the bus stops (or the edges connecting them) whose value is an array containing the the times?

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: The only useful reference I could find was this: https://neo4j.com/blog/journey-planning-why-i-love-cypher/?_ga=2.262081421.1446045581.1564409406-844942336.1528206011. Unfortunately, the page is just a presentation and lacks many details. You can make out some of the implicit passages.Very likely you will have to modify or discard some of them according to your purpose. There was also a personal page of the author somewhere (maybe github).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your main concern is how to model schedule-times for each line. If I understand your concern correctly, it's because each line can have multiple shifts a day between two bus stops.

It's doable to put all schedule-times in an array and store it as a property of bus stops. However, it would be quite hard to extend to other transportation choices other than buses. So in a more scalable graph model, the vertex could be a place, and the edge would be the transportation (not limited to bus) between two places. Any attribute of a transportation choice can be a property of the edge, including time schedules.

But let's take bus as an example. So suppose you have m lines between the same two bus stops, A and B, and for each line you want to schedule n shifts per day (in reality n can be different for different lines but that doesn't matter that much). Then you can create m*n edges between A and B. In this case, each edge has only one attribute as its scheduled time. Then you can use rankings to differentiate the edges. An alternative is to create just m edges and define the n shifts as properties on each edge. In this case you have n attributes for each  edge as its scheduled times. Obviously the former way is friendlier to later queries.